# My tableDnD dragHandle not limiting drag to one table cell in FireFox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I think I am missing something quite simple but the problem I have is even though I add the dragHandle: '.dragHandle' the entire tr is still draggable. I only want the first td to have the draggable functionality. Here is the example I've been working on. It's pretty much identical to the example on http://isocra.com/2008/02/table-drag-and-drop-jquery-plugin/

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#table-5').tableDnD({
        dragHandle: ".dragHandle"
    });

    $("#table-5 tr").hover(function () {
        $(this.cells[0]).addClass('showDragHandle');
    }, function () {
        $(this.cells[0]).removeClass('showDragHandle');
    });

});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="tableDemo">
        <table id="table-5" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
            <tbody>
                <tr id="table5-row-1">
                    <td class="dragHandle"></td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>One</td>
                    <td>some text</td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="table5-row-2">
                    <td class="dragHandle"></td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>Two</td>
                    <td>some text</td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="table5-row-3">
                    <td class="dragHandle"></td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>Three</td>
                    <td>some text</td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="table5-row-4">
                    <td class="dragHandle"></td>
                    <td>4</td>
                    <td>Four</td>
                    <td>some text</td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="table5-row-5">
                    <td class="dragHandle"></td>
                    <td>5</td>
                    <td>Five</td>
                    <td>some text</td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="table5-row-6">
                    <td class="dragHandle"></td>
                    <td>6</td>
                    <td>Six</td>
                    <td>some text</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

I am using the latest tableDnD version from: https://github.com/isocra/TableDnD/blob/master/js/jquery.tablednd.js

and this is css I'm styling to my page: https://github.com/isocra/TableDnD/blob/master/tablednd.css

Any direction here would be much appreciated.

**Update**
I just found out this example I posted works for me in chrome and IE11. However, it doesn't work for me in Firefox. So refining my question to "in FireFox."

Comment: It seems to work for me. I copied your code and the extension's code into a jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/L5pMB/ Your code starts around line 665. Maybe something else is interfering?

Comment: @WetNoodles Are you using firefox?

Comment: After checking Firefox, maybe I'm misinterpreting the problem, but it still seems to work. I can only drag the table row when I drag from the first td. Or do you mean only the first td should move? Which version of Firefox are you using?

Comment: Yes your jsFiddle works for me in all browsers. It must be something with my build.